# About Iterator and Iterable interface constructors

Tags: java

Please help me to understand below:

Since `Iterable` and `Iterator` are interfaces so coding `Iterator<T> it = new Iterator<T> ();` will get `error(interface has no constructor ?)`.

But why the codes below work OK? `new Iterable<String> () { --- }` and its nesting `new Iterator<String>()` are both constructors of interfaces `Iterable` and `Iterator`, just they return the anonymous objects vs. "it" the real object.

```
public class MultiIterableClass extends IterableClass {
    public Iterable<String> reversed() { 
        return new Iterable<String>() {
            public Iterator<String> iterator() { 
                return new Iterator<String>() { 
                    int current = words.length -1;

                    public boolean hasNext() { return current > -1; }
                    public String next() { return words[current--]; }
                    public void remove() { // Not implemented
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The 2nd question is that the above codes(from Thinking in Java 4th-Ed) are complicated with constructor nesting another constructor, what are the `reversed()` return ? Return an `Iterable-object` or return `Iterator-object` or both? If both what is the return order?

Thanks

ZW

Comment: Are you asking what the difference is between `new Iterator();` and `new Iterator() { ... };`?

Comment: Consider reading about [anonymous classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) and [inner classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html).

Comment: As for #2, `reversed()` returns a (object that implements) `Iterable`.  The [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface specifies that the object has a `iterator()` method, which returns an object that [implements `Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is the concept of anonymous inner classes.
when you are saying new Iterator(){---} you are just implementing that interface.